# Get the latest value for each couple (name,address)

Tags: sql

I have the following table for which I need to get the latest values for the group ( name , address ).
This means I need to have the max(time) for each ( name, address ) couple and get the last_read for that time value.
How can I do that in one select query ?

[image: table links_data]

Comment: Subquery where you group on name and adress and fetch the max(time) name, adress and join that result with your tabl is the most common way.. i pretty sure you can find examples on this website when you search “SQL max value per group”.. You should update the question to also include the expected result as a formatted data table

Answer (score 1):

I think below should work for you, you need to use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`

```
select max([time]),
    [name],
    [address]
from yourTable
group by [name], 
    [address]
```

**EDIT**

You can try other answers or check below, which uses temp table

```
select max([time]) as last_read_time,
    [name],
    [address]
into #temp_table
from yourTable
group by [name], 
    [address]

select last_read
from yourTable as yt
    inner join #temp_table t
        on yt.[name] = t.[name]
        and yt.[time] = t.last_read_time

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table', 'U') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I have tried this query where I added the column last_read but unfortunately it gives the correct values for max(time) but wrong values for last_read.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, a correlated subquery is a good approach:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select max(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where t2.name = t.name and t2.address = t.address
               );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(name, address, time)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` if your dbms support

```
select * from 
(select *,row_number() over(partition by name,address order by time desc) rn
) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked.
I finally found the following query that works :

```
select 
    l2.MAX t, 
    l.name, 
    l.address, 
    l.last_read 
from links_data l 
inner join (select name, 
                address, 
                max(time) as "MAX" 
            from links_data 
            group by name, address) l2 
        on l.name = l2.name 
        and l.address = l2.address  
        and l.time = l2.MAX;
```

Thanks everyone.